# In Android TV leanback UI BrowseFragment how could I find when HeadersFragment is put away?

Tags: android, leanback

I'm writing a POC Android TV app for my company based on our existing mobile OTT product and backend.

I'm modifying the `PageAndListRowFragment` example from Google's `Leanback` Showcase code.

When a header option is selected (with OK or right arrow) I want the `RowsFragment` side to popup an `AlertDialog` to let me filter the content displayed ('all', 'latest', etc).

My problem is that I have the `AlertDialog` in the `RowsFragment` `onCreate` So, It displays as soon as the `HeadersFragment` is highlighted. This stops the user from scrolling down the header smoothly and is confusing because you still have to select the header item after the dialog.

Most advice on the web seems to point to overriding the `OnItemViewClickedListener` function on the `HeadersFragment` but I can't find a way to do this. (The `leanback` showcase uses the deprecated `BrowseFragement` code, Not `BrowseSupportFragment` and if I try to change up I get into `FragmentFactory` errors I'm not experienced enough to resolve).

I've also tried implementing `isShowingHeaders()` in the RowsFragment.

I've tried to find a stage of the fragment lifecycle in either `HeadersFragment` or `RowsFragment` that will let me popup the dialog when the `RowsFragment` is full screen without success.

I'm already using the `PageRowFragmentFactory` code in the `leanback` showcase code to send an `EventBus` message containing the header option chosen and was hoping to send a similar message to trigger the dialog.

I've tried setting up a `setOnHeaderViewSelectedListener` on the `BrowseFragment` but can't seem to successfully get it invoked.

I'm new to Android programming so apologies for my ignorance, but I'm determined to make this work somehow.

Any suggestions on the approach would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: In case this helps someone else... the best way I've found so far to do this is to set up an headersFragment.setOnHeaderClickedListener that catches an OK button press on the header menu. That sends an eventBus signal to the browse fragment so that it will display the content filtering dialog. if you hit right cursor on the header menu it goes straight into the browse fragment without the dialog/filter. It isn't what I was aiming for, but it kind of works, once the user knows they can choose the two different behaviors by how they select the header menu option (OK or right arrow).